# NodeJS 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, http-headers

I am trying to create a middleware that will check user credentials, and if successful, create a JWT with the user information. I want to create a cookie and then store the JWT within the cookie, but I can't seem to get it working properly. After hitting the login method on post, I get a 404 'Not Found' error, saying it "Cannot POST /authenticate". What am I missing?

Route:

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res, next){
    middleware.login(req, res, next);
});
```

Middleware:

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    User.findByUsername(username,function(err, user){
        if(err){
            res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed.' });
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        }
        if(user && !user.isuserenabled){
            res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        }
        if (!UserSchema.comparePassword(password,user.user_password )) {
            res.send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        }
        res.cookie('yummyCookie', jwt.sign(
            //payload, secret, options, [callback]
            {
                id: user.user_id,
                email: user.email,
                name: user.firstname + " " + user.lastname,
                role: user.role
            },
            config.secret, // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE
            {expiresIn: "1h"}, {secure: true, httpOnly: true}));
        return next();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are receiving a `404 not found` is because you are actually not sending any response, but simply passing the execution to the next handler. As no handler is matched after that express returns 404.
The `app.post` is actually called, but as you are calling `next()` it expects another middleware to handle the request. Here is a pretty basic example that your route is actually invoked, but the execution is passed to the next middleware in the Chain of responsibility. As there is none - you receive the error.

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
 console.log('called');
 next();
});

app.listen(5000);
```

This will write 'called' to the console, but still return 404. What you can do is add another handler after successful authentication which would look something like this:

```js
app.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('OK').end();
});
```

or you can incorporate that login in the middleware itself instead of calling `next()`

Comment: Does something have to be sent at the end (in this case, 'OK') or can I just call res.end(); ?

Comment: You could just call `res.end()` and it will return an empty body with a HTTP status 200